# Kotlin multiplatform library exporting dependencies for JVM

Tags: kotlin, gradle, kmm

I’m creating a multiplatform for jvm and iOS on kotlin using Gradle.
For the jvm, even if I define my dependencies as **implementation**, they are included in the library generated .pom and with **runtime** scope.

By using **implementation**, I was expecting that these dependencies are not passed to the library consumer.

But, when I use this library on my other jvm project, Gradle is importing the library-specific version. Not the one that I set in my application dependencies.

in this case, I'm doing a downgrade. The library is using the dependency version 1.4.1, and on the application I want to use version 1.4.0.1.

Comment: So what exactly would you like to happen instead?

Comment: Thanks @Joffrey. I added more detais to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By using implementation, I was expecting that these dependencies are not passed to the library consumer.

If you expect the consumers to provide those transitive dependencies themselves, you should use `compileOnly` instead of `implementation`.

The difference between `api` and `implementation` is that transitive dependencies declared with `api` will be visible and usable by the application by just depending on your library (seen at compile time AND runtime). With `implementation`, the transitive dependency will still be here at runtime but will not be visible on the compile classpath of the consuming application, so you cannot use the transitive dependency's declarations in the application's code.

Have a look at the table here:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html

If you stick with `implementation`, you can still force a version for the transitive dependency in Gradle by using `strictly` or by excluding it and redeclaring it yourself. See the doc:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html